# PHP Mongo DB remove stopping proccess with no error

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to get rid of a document by `_id`, but the PHP process stops without error, and no error in `access.log`, and no output if i assign a variable to `remove()`. Using mongodb:
`version v2.4.9`

```
    $connection = new MongoClient();
    if($connection == NULL) {
        return "some msg";
    }
    $db = $connection->main;
    $collection = $db->users;
    $document = $collection->findOne(array('email' => $user->email));
    if($document == NULL) {
        // do some stuff, works fine.
    } else {
        $id = $document["_id"];
        echo "id=".$id                            // outputs: 5469a22600a8ebe8418b4567
        if($document["confirm"] != "true") {
            echo "confirmed not true"             // outputs fine
            $collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), true);
            echo "hello!";                        // never occurs
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I tried this, and no output:

```
            try { 
                $collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), true);
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

EDIT: I found an answer, but I don't understand the answer because every example I've seen includes the `true` argument. So I won't self answer this question and leave it up to an expert.

This doesn't work:

```
$collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), true);
```

This doesn't work:

```
$collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), false);
```

This works:

```
$collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));
```

Comment: Have you ensured you have turned up the php error_reporting and set a log method (to file or screen) for the PHP process?

Comment: Yes with this script i get the usual PHP errors in my error.log if i miss out a semi-colon etc.., i'm tailing it constantly

Comment: Error reporting wasn't turned on fully. `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` fixed that part atleast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can explain your problem but I cannot explain why you are not seeing errors, there must be something odd in your PHP setup.

Anyway, as to why your `boolean` only value for the second parameter does not work: it is because the PHP driver expects an array: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php the examples you worked from were either incredibly old (Since the change happened 1.0.5 http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php#refsect1-mongocollection.remove-changelog) or incorrect.

Comment: Ah I see all the other pages were old and I mis-read this one - A 4 y/o comment at the bottom put me wrong. Cheers!